# Questions about good production practice

Tags: discussion

I have questions about practices for software in production, and the transition from development to production. **Is Stack Overflow the appropriate place to ask these questions?**

Some are high-level, like "How should I think about blah blah blah?" and some are more granular "If I'm using Meteor and MongoDB, how can I migrate the database format when there's already data in the database?", etc.

Comment: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Answer (score 0):

No, those questions do not belong on Stack Overflow. As long as you are *not* asking for opinions or recommendations, you might be able to ask your design-related questions at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) instead. Be sure to read their [On-Topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section to know exactly what is and is not appropriate there.

Comment: Read their help section and take their tour to know what kind of questions are on-topic there before asking.